# Lucene queries and special characters

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am inserting tuples into ElasticSearch using Logstash.
Tuples have the following format:

> 753469038|4057|1|0|99031479997|0|350771|1|47382594591370772|6050143149551329|2400|+|3.5
>
> 753453038|5345|1|0|23543643667|0|346661|1|47382594591370772|6050143149551329|2200|-|4.5
>
> ...

Logstash parses for each field successfully. They are all correctly imported into ES. I am using Kibana to query my data but am having trouble querying for the **penultimate** field **(+ or -)**.
I've tried numerous different ways to query for these symbols but cannot seem to retrieve them.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you use a regexp querydsl filter, for the +/- ?

Comment: What analyzer do you use? Do + and - sybmols become terms after analyzing? Thry this to check http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html